# Pattern match for string,number and brackets in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to know the pattern for the below string.

Example: `test [123],test,123test,1234`

If string contains alphabets,number and square bracket (opening,closing) then pattern should match for the same.

Comment: So your pattern should accept `[`,`]`,`,`, space, chars and numbers

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
"[a-zA-Z\\d\\[\\]]+"
```

Your request is ambiguous... What about the commas? And spaces?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes... pattern should accept space as well not comma.

Comment: To accept space as well Pattern should be **`"[a-zA-Z \\d\\[\\]]+"`** like this.. Thanks for you help. :)